# Unable to execute CURL command through java Runtime.getRuntime().exec()

Tags: java, curl

I am executing a curl command using java.

```
curl -i --user "OAMADMIN_tenant_358922247351079_svc_358922247369079_APPID:Iuj.2swilg5fhv" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json" -H 'X-USER-IDENTITY-DOMAIN-NAME: tenant_358922247351079' -H "X-RESOURCE-IDENTITY-DOMAIN-NAME: tenant_358922247351079" --request GET "https://slc04yre-1.dev.oraclecorp.com:4443/oam/services/rest/11.1.2.0.0/oauth/admin/Clients?name=myMCS_svc_358922247369079_MCS_Client_OAUTHCLIENT"
```

I want to get the output of this curl command in my code,but my stdoutput is coming out to be empty.

```
 private static String executeCommand(String command) {
        StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();

        Process p;
        try {
            p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    p.getInputStream()));
            //p.waitFor();
            String line = "";
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println("line="+line);
                output.append(line + "\n");
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return output.toString();

    }
```

Tried executing the curl command manually, its working fine.
Then I printed the standard error, and I can see:

```
   [testng] error line=
   [testng] error line=curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'application'
   [testng] error line=
   [testng] error line=curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'application'
   [testng] error line=
   [testng] error line=curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'tenant_359516638431079''
   [testng] error line=
   [testng] error line=curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'tenant_359516638431079"'
   [testng] error line=
   [testng] error line=curl: (1) Unsupported protocol: "https
```

When curl command is executed manually, its working fine then why not through Runtime.getRuntime() ?

Kindly suggest!! Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I am building my command like this:
String cmd = "curl -i --user \""
    + appId
    + ":"
    + appIdPwd
    + "\" -H \"Content-Type: application/json\" -H \"Accept: application/json\" "
    + "-H 'X-USER-IDENTITY-DOMAIN-NAME: " + tenantName
    + "' -H \"X-RESOURCE-IDENTITY-DOMAIN-NAME: " + tenantName
    + "\" --request GET \""
    + url.substring(0, url.lastIndexOf("/"))
    + "/oam/services/rest/11.1.2.0.0/oauth/admin/Clients?name="
    + client + "\"";

Comment: Why do you execute external `curl` process? You can easily send and handle any http request directly in `java`. It would be much more efficient! See e.g. : http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-send-http-request-getpost-in-java/

Comment: Another example with `https` request is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6927427/how-to-send-https-post-request-in-java

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like the data shell/console is interpreting/changing characters.  For example the following line:

`-H "Content-Type: application/json"`

... seems to be getting interpreted as three different arguments:

`-H Content-Type:` and `application` and `/json` by the shell/console.

Try breaking the command string down into an array of components using the format:

`exec(String[] cmdarray)`

That way it will be clear to the shell/console which arguments are grouped together.

Here is a test in groovy that proves the point:

```
def Object executeCommand(command) {

   def proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
   def sout = new StringBuffer()
   def serr = new StringBuffer()

   proc.consumeProcessOutput(sout, serr)
   proc.waitFor()

   return [ 'sout':sout.toString(), 'serr':serr.toString() ]
}   

response = executeCommand('''curl --silent --show-error -H "Accept: application/json" --request GET "https://education.cloudant.com/"''')
assert response['sout'] == ''
assert response['serr'].startsWith( 'curl: (6) Could not resolve host: application' )

response = executeCommand(['curl', '--silent',  '--show-error',  '-H', 'Accept: application/json',  '--request', 'GET', 'https://education.cloudant.com/'] as String[] )
assert response['sout'].startsWith('{"couchdb":"Welcome","version":"1.0.2","cloudant_build":"2367"}')
assert response['serr'] == ''
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Chris. I tried breaking the curl command into an array and it worked. Thanks!!

Comment: @Sammi Can you provide the code which worked. I'm having a similar problem.