# CURL POST request in kotlin using Runtime.getRuntime.exec errors with data

Tags: curl, kotlin, plugins, intellij-plugin

I'm building a plugin in intellij and want to make a curl request. The plugin is written in kotlin.

The following curl request works:

```
            val comd = arrayOf(
                "curl",
                "-X",
                "GET",
                "-H",
                "Authorization: AUTH_TOKEN",
                "https://api.bitrise.io/v0.1/me"
            )
```

But the following POST request with data doesn't:

```
            val comd = arrayOf(
                "curl",
                "-X",
                "POST",
                "https://api.bitrise.io/v0.1/apps/appslug/builds",
                "-H",
                "Authorization: AUTH_TOKEN",
                " -d $data"
            )
```

I'm using this function to run the request:

```
    private fun executeCommandLine(project: Project, comd: Array<String>) {
        val process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(comd)
        val processHandler: ProcessHandler = OSProcessHandler(process, "clear", Charset.forName("UTF-8"))
        consoleView.attachToProcess(processHandler)
        processHandler.startNotify()
    }
```

It just throws an error:

```
curl: (3) nested brace in URL position 18:
 -d {"hook_info":{"type":"bitrise"},"build_params":{"branch":"master"}}
```

I've tried running the request with **-g** switch for globbing error. But then I run into another one:

```
curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
```

What am I missing here?

PS: I've had to break my curl command into an array otherwise it doesn't work. Check this: [Unable to execute CURL command through java Runtime.getRuntime().exec()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30301212/unable-to-execute-curl-command-through-java-runtime-getruntime-exec)

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Return the curl command to a string and then try using this function from @leondepeon's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59771204/8651748)

```
    /** Run a system-level command.
 * Note: This is a system independent java exec (e.g. | doesn't work). For shell: prefix with "bash -c"
 * Inputting the string in stdIn (if any), and returning stdout and stderr as a string. */
fun exec(cmd: String, stdIn: String = "", captureOutput:Boolean = false, workingDir: File = File(".")): String? {
    try {
        val process = ProcessBuilder(*cmd.split("\\s".toRegex()).toTypedArray())
                .directory(workingDir)
                .redirectOutput(if (captureOutput) ProcessBuilder.Redirect.PIPE else ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT)
                .redirectError(if (captureOutput) ProcessBuilder.Redirect.PIPE else ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT)
                .start().apply {
                    if (stdIn != "") {
                        outputStream.bufferedWriter().apply {
                            write(stdIn)
                            flush()
                            close()
                        }
                    }
                    waitFor(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                }
        if (captureOutput) {
            return process.inputStream.bufferedReader().readText()
        }
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
    return null
}
```

Also, if working on Windows, [be wary of the single quote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24232441/8651748).